# How to mass delete manually assigned accounts in territory management?

Tags: account, territory-management, territory

as you can see in the picture, the task is simple, but instead of going one by one and manually deleting each manually assigned accounts in territory management, how would one go about deleting each block of manually assigned accounts in each territoy? Also, there is no assignment rules attached to them as well.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
List<ObjectTerritory2Association> accountAssociations = [
    SELECT Id, AssociationCause, ObjectId, SobjectType 
    FROM ObjectTerritory2Association 
    WHERE Territory2Id = '0MI7A000000DViPWAW' AND AssociationCause = 'Territory2Manual'
];
for (ObjectTerritory2Association accountAssociation: accountAssociations) {
    if (accountAssociation.SobjectType == 'Account') {
        accountIds.add(accountAssociation.ObjectId);
    }
}
Database.delete(accountIds);
```

Hi,
Add Territory2Id to the script to delete Accounts from the territory.
Not sure why filtering by SobjectType doesn't work, but it could be done in Apex as well